# How do i use constructor in swift

Tags: swift, constructor, menu

Im trying to create multiple slide up menus in swift but i don't want to have to keep duplicating classes and only changing one thing so can i pass in an array of the options that need to be displayed on the menu through a constructor or do i have to use different classes?

For example to create the slide up menu i use the following class:

where the array of Settings is what i want to be displayed on the menu and that is the only difference in all my classes.

So is there a way that i can pass in the array when i call the class so that i can use one class for all menus or do i have to duplicate the class and have the array of settings in each class?

```
private var reuseidentifier = "cellId"

class SettingsLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

weak var delegate: SettingsLauncherDelegate?

let blackView = UIView()
let headerId = "headerId"
let cellHeight = CGFloat(50)
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 35, green: 35, blue: 35, alpha: 1)
    return cv
}()

let settings: [Setting] = {
   return [
        Setting(name: "Settings", imageName: "gear"),
        Setting(name: "Notifications", imageName: "bell"),
        Setting(name: "My Store", imageName: "bag"),
        Setting(name: "Search User", imageName: "magnifyingglass"),
        Setting(name: "Sign Out", imageName: "arrow.backward"),
        Setting(name: "Cancel", imageName: "xmark")
   ]
}()

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    collectionView.register(SettingsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier)
    self.collectionView.register(HeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

}

func showSettings() {
    
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))
        
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(settings.count + 1) * cellHeight + 50
        let y = window.frame.height - height
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        
        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

        } completion: { (nil) in
            
        }
    }
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        } completion: { (nil) in
            
    }
}


@objc func handleDismissAndPresenetController(setting: Setting) {
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }
        } completion: { (nil) in
            self.delegate?.settingDidSelected(setting: setting)
    }
}


//MARK: - Header

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath)
    
    return header
}


//MARK: - Collection View

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settings.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    
    
    let setting = settings[indexPath.row]
    
    
    if cell.setting?.name == "Notifications" {
        let cell = SettingsCell()
        cell.badge.isHidden = false
    }
    
    cell.setting = setting

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: cellHeight)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
    handleDismissAndPresenetController(setting: setting)
}
}
```

Im not sure how i would do this as i need to call the show method in another class to present the menu like this:

```
    let settingsLauncher = SettingsLauncher()
    settingsLauncher.showSettings()
```

Comment: whats the issue in creating a convenience/required initializer for your class and pass array to it as argument?

Comment: I'm not sure how i would do this and pass in the parameters when i call the method. I've updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. This version uses inheritance of a common class

I used SwiftUI but the `struct`s that end with `View` can be easily substituted with you `UIKit` `UIView`s

```
//Common Class
class MyObject {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
    
    init(name: String, imageName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
//Class that inherits
class Setting: MyObject{
    var typeDescription: String = "I am a Setting"
}
//Class that inherits
class CRUD: MyObject{
    var useDescription: String = "Use me to persist"
}
class DataSource{
    let settings: [Setting] = [Setting(name: "Settings", imageName: "gear"), Setting(name: "Notification", imageName: "bell")]
    let cruds: [CRUD] = [CRUD(name: "Edit", imageName: "pencil"), CRUD(name: "Add", imageName: "plus")]
    var objects: [MyObject] = [Setting(name: "Settings", imageName: "gear"),CRUD(name: "Edit", imageName: "pencil"), Setting(name: "Notification", imageName: "bell"), CRUD(name: "Add", imageName: "plus")]
    
}
struct ParentView: View {
    let dataSource: DataSource = DataSource()
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Section(header: Text("Settings"), content: {ReusableListView(objects: dataSource.settings)})
            Section(header: Text("CRUDs"), content: {ReusableListView(objects: dataSource.cruds)})
            Section(header: Text("Combo"), content: {ReusableListView(objects: dataSource.objects)})
            
            
        }
    }
}
//Shared/Reusable View
struct ReusableListView: View {
    var objects: [MyObject]
    
    init(objects: [MyObject]){
        self.objects = objects
    }
    var body: some View {
        List(objects, id: \.id){obj in
            VStack{
                Label(
                    title: { Text(obj.name) },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: obj.imageName) })
                //Add Something unique
                if obj is Setting{
                    SettingCellView(object: obj as! Setting)
                }else if obj is CRUD{
                    CRUDCellView(object: obj as! CRUD)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
//Unique View
struct SettingCellView: View {
    var object: Setting
    var body: some View {
        Text(object.typeDescription)
    }
}
//Unique View
struct CRUDCellView: View {
    var object: CRUD
    var body: some View {
        Text(object.useDescription)
    }
}
```